# How to remove all anotation in evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

I spent so much time in reading PDF, so I need an anotation feature.

I like how Okular save the anotation in xml file, so I can easily share my clean PDF, and export anotation when I need.

now I use **Evince** to avoid KDE dependency, because Evince now support annotation (Highlight, Note).

But, how to remove all annotation at once, it's a pain if I have to keep 2 same PDF just to make me easy to share the clean one.

Note: Foxit support [deleting all annotations at once](http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/17710-how-to-delete-all-annotations-comments-in-a-pdf), but I tried to use the libre application first.

Comment: Did you actually check to see how many KDE dependencies are already on your system and what else would by pulled in by installing okular? If not, try `apt-get install -s okular` to run a simulation. There's no need for `sudo`.

Comment: because there is no other choice, willy nilly, I installed Okular already, I always check dependency using `apt-cache depends foo`. Actually I want to have minimal system since I don't use GNOME or KDE.
as long as there is no other choice, I still use Okular.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question.

Comment: take a look at this feature [foxit delete all anotation](http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/17710-how-to-delete-all-annotations-comments-in-a-pdf)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this now? There have passed several years after this question. The documentation proposes to remove annotations one by one. https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotations-delete.html.en